# Netty IO check if Server closed

Tags: java, client, handler, netty, server

how can I check if the Server closed/shut down on the client-side? I want to notice the user when the Server closed.
Is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a connection is closed, your handlers will be notified via `channelInactive()` method.

Comment: When the channel is closed *by this application.*

Comment: What is 'this application'? `channelInactive()` will be invoked regardless which side closed the channel.